# How to color a table column

Tags: tables, multicol, multirow, multicolumn, colortbl

I have this sample table. I made the script below but I still need few requirements that I do not know how to:

1) I need to apply the gray color one row above (i.e. the cell which contains the word JOINT)

2) I want the `\hline` (the black line) to be visible above the gray color. They are now hidden behind the column.

3) I need to remove the extra white after the last row of the gray color

See this figure:
[image]

Please edit the following script:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{llncs}
\usepackage{colortbl} % for table colors 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell, booktabs, caption}
\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{adjustbox} 
\newcommand{\normal}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{#1}}
\usepackage{sistyle} % for numbers 
\SIthousandsep{,} % for numbers

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Abstract
\end{abstract}

\section{Section1}
\begin{table}[!tp]
    \centering
    \caption{Some table}
    \label{tab:redirection} 
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{20pt}}>{\columncolor[gray]{0.8}}r>{\columncolor[gray]{0.8}}r@{\hspace{10pt}}rr@{\hspace{10pt}}rr}
            \toprule
            Row \#1
            & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\num{111}} \\
            \midrule 
            Row \#1 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{JOINT} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Col\#1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Col\#2}   \\
            \hline 
            Row \#3
            & \num{222}&(0.11\%) & \num{88} &(0.11\%) & \num{111}  \\
            \hline
            Row \#4
            & \num{555} & (0.33\%) & \num{222}& (0.11\%) & \num{22}& (0.11\%) \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The white strips come from the padding above and below booktabs rules. So I set it to 0, and replaced it with a small value for `\extrarowheight`. As to the bove cell, it comes from this cell being a  `\multicolumn`. Fianlly, I replaced loading `sistyle` with `siunitx`. So I propose this code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{llncs}
\usepackage{colortbl} % for table colors
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell, booktabs, caption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\newcommand{\normal}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{#1}}
\usepackage{siunitx} 

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Abstract
\end{abstract}

\section{Section1}
\begin{table}[!tp]
    \centering
    \caption{Some table}
    \label{tab:redirection}
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
        \begin{tabular}{l@{\hspace{20pt}}>{\columncolor[gray]{0.8}}r>{\columncolor[gray]{0.8}}r@{\hspace{10pt}}rr@{\hspace{10pt}}rr}
            \toprule
            Row \#1
            & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\num{111}} \\
            \midrule
            Row \#1 & \multicolumn{2}{>{\columncolor[gray]{0.8}[2.8pt][1.4pt]}c@{\hspace{10pt}}}{JOINT} &\multicolumn{2}{@{\hspace{10pt}}c}{Col\#1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Col\#2} \\
            \hline
            Row \#3
            & \num{222}&(0.11\%) & \num{88} &(0.11\%) & \num{111} \\
            \hline
            Row \#4
            & \num{555} & (0.33\%) & \num{222}& (0.11\%) & \num{22}& (0.11\%) \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me how to make the black hosrizontal lines above the gray color?

Comment: ??? They're here. Maybe there's a problem with your pdfviewer. If you zoom in, you'll see the black lines, normally.

Comment: There is a very thin vertical white line for the rows under the JOINT. How to remove them?

Comment: Oh! yes. It disappears zooming at 2400%. You can use the overhang (optional)  arguments for the first  coloured column, using this code in the table preamble: `>{\columncolor[gray]{0.8}[\tabcolsep][7pt]}r`.

Comment: `using this code in the table preamble` what is the table preamble? Can you please specify where exactly? Are you answering my question about the thin white line in the grey cells Row#3 and R#4? Can you update your script and point what/where is it added?

Comment: You mean in the `\begin{tabular}`?

Comment: The table preamble is what comes just after `\begin{tabular}`. Here is what I have: `{l@{\hspace{20pt}}>{\columncolor[gray]{0.8}[\tabcolsep][7pt]}r>{\columncolor[gray]{0.8}}r@{\hspace{10pt}}rr@{\hspace{10pt}}rr}`. The overhang  on the right side of the column is set to 7pt because the default value for  `\tabcolsep` is 6 pt.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

I would not use `adjustbox`. Instead it is better to use `tabular*` with `width equal to text width. Color of`multicolumn`cell should be defined by`cellcolor`. For bigger space between column's groups  I would insert additional empty columns.

More space above and below cells contents can be achieved by use of `cellspace` package and for lines used `\hlineB` from `boldline` package.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{llncs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % for table colors
\usepackage{array,
            boldline, % part of shipunov bundle
            cellspace,
            makecell,
            multirow}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\newcommand{\normal}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{#1}}
\usepackage{sistyle} % for numbers
\SIthousandsep{,} % for numbers

\begin{document}
\section{Section1}
\begin{table}[!tp]
    \centering
    \caption{Some table}
    \label{tab:redirection}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{7pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{
                    Sl @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                    c
*{2}{>{\columncolor{gray!80}\centering}p{3em}@{}}
                    c
*{2}{>{\centering}p{3em}}
                    c
*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3em}}
                }
    \hlineB{3}
Row \#1 & \multicolumn{9}{c}{\num{111}} \\
   \hlineB{1.5}
Row \#1 && \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{\cellcolor{gray!80}{JOINT}}
            && \multicolumn{2}{c}{Col\#1}
                && \multicolumn{2}{c}{Col\#2}   \\
   \hlineB{1.5}
Row \#3 && \num{222}
            &(0.11\%)
                && \num{88}
                    & (0.11\%)
                        && \num{111}
                            &           \\
   \hlineB{1.5}
Row \#4 && \num{555}
            & (0.33\%)
                && \num{222}
                    & (0.11\%)
                        && \num{22}
                            & (0.11\%) \\
   \hlineB{3}
   \end{tabular*}
   \end{table}
```